# Find the polynomial $P$ of smallest degree with rational coefficients and leading coefficient $1$ such that $ P(49^{1/3}+7^{1/3})=4 $

Tags: polynomials, proof-verification

> Find the polynomial $P$ of smallest degree with rational coefficients
>   and leading coefficient $1$ such that $$ P(49^{1/3}+7^{1/3})=4 $$
>
> (Source:NYSML)

**My attempt**
Let $$ 49^{1/3}+7^{1/3}=x$$
Then,
\begin{array}
((49^{1/3})^3 &=(x-7^{1/3})^{3}  \\
49 &=x^3-7-3x^2\cdot 7^{1/3}+3x \cdot 7^{2/3} \\
\end{array}

So I have $$x^3+x^2 (-3\cdot 7^{1/3})+x(3\cdot 7^{2/3})-56 =0 $$
Define $$Q(x)=x^3+x^2 (-3\cdot 7^{1/3})+x(3\cdot 7^{2/3})-56 $$
making the substitution $x=7^{1/3} \cdot t $,
I have $$F(t)=\cfrac{Q(7^{1/3} \cdot t)}{7}=t^3+t^2(-21)+21t-56$$

Now I am quite stuck on how I should continue...

Comment: You have a polynomial of rational coeff and leading coeff 1. You just have to prove this is the minimal order. You have to prove that no polynomial of order 2 fits the bill (order 1 is trivial).

Comment: Your $P(x)$ = x^3-(56+3(7^{4/3}+7^{5/3})+4$ does not have rational coefficiencts:  $56+3(7^{4/3}+7^{5/3}$ is certainly not rational.

Comment: I can't find the way to transform my $Q(x)$ into a polynomial with rational coefficients without changing its root $49^{1/3}+7^{1/3}$.There's some slick transformation I guess.

Comment: The first attempt (cubing directly) came a lot closer. We have $x^3=56+3(7^{5/3}+7^{4/3})=56+21x$. Now deal with the $4$ business, and you will have your polynomial. Then (depending on the source of the problem) you may or may not have to prove minimality.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That was neat...Can you give me some hint on how to prove minimality ?

Comment: It is easiest with some theory, using the fact that your polynomial is irreducible over the rationals. If we don't have theory, it is s mattter of proving your number is not the root of a quadratic with rational coefficients. Kind of like the proof of irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ but a lot messier.  If it is a graded mechanically contest problem (full credit for correct answer, 0 otherwise) you need not worry about it.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Okay,thanks for the help ! I go back to the drawing board.

Comment: But at least the finding the polynomial is finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first attempt (cubing $49^{1/3}+7^{1/3}$) came close to finishing. Let $a$ be our number. Cubing, we find that
$$a^3=56+3(7^{5/3}+7^{4/3})=56+21a.$$
So if $Q(x)$ is the polynomial $x^3-21x-56$, then $Q(a)=0$. Dealing with the fact that we want $P(a)=4$ is now easy.

We sketch a proof that this polynomial $P(x)$ has minimal degree. First show that $a$ is not a root of a polynomial of degree $1$ with rational coefficients. This can be handled by the Rational Root Theorem. To show that $a$ is not a root of a polynomial of degree $2$ with rational coefficients, suppose that $W(x)$ is such a polynomial. Then the remainder $R(x)$ when we divide $P(x)$ by $W(x)$ has degree $\le 1$, and $R(a)=0$, which is impossible.

Comment: Just to be sure I am understanding your last point.We have a contradiction since $R(a)=0$ would imply $a$ to be a rational number ?

Answer (score 2):

A fast way to get the polynomial is to observe that
$$(x+y)^3=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^3+y^3=x^3+y^3+3xy(x+y)  (**)$$

Now with your $a=49^{1/3}+7^{1/3}$ setting $x=49^{1/3}, y=7^{1/3}$ you have 
$$x^3=49, y^3=7, xy=7$$

Replace those in $(**)$ and you are done.